# summation of series of powers $ n^{nix} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

is the series ..

$$ \sum _{n=2}^{\infty}n^{kin} $$

here k is a real number

is convergen or divergent ??, for example perhaps we can copare it to the series $$ \sum _{n=2}^{\infty}n^{ix} $$ which is divergent for every fixed 'x'

what criterion could i use to check the convergence or divergence of the series ??

this series is related to the fourier series  $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}cos(xnln(n)) $$

Comment: Does the general term tend to $0$?

Comment: don't know.. i would have for big N the term $ \infty ^{i \infty} $ which makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
|n^{ikn}|=|e^{ikn\ln n}|=1
$$
for all $n$.
Do you know a criterion that could help now?